# Is possible to select different table cells for different threads in same sampler in JMeter record and play back

Tags: jmeter, record, playback

I want to load test following scenario.

### 1.Submit student details in basic data insert page.

### Result : Added record just bind into table grid in same page.

2.Click on edit button of particular added record in table. 
3.Change student name and click on save again.

My key load test scenario is record edit scenario. I used CSV data config for test parameters. I want to know is it possible to select different table cells with different thread requests in same sampler to test my scenario in same tread group.

Please refer the attachment for sample screen.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9JWa.png)

Answer (score 0):

[CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) element has **Sharing Mode** setting, by default it is `All Threads`.

This means that CSV file is shared across all JMeter threads and each Thread (virtual user) takes the next line each iteration so default configuration should be fine for your use case, just add more threads and/or loops in [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) or [Loop Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller) and JMeter will pick up the next line for each thread/iteration.

See [CSV Data Set Config in Sharing Mode - Made Easy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/csv-data-set-config-in-sharing-mode-made-easy) article for more information.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  But my requirement is different. Its just like this example.  I have a web application page to submit student details. Its has two text boxes  for submit student id and name. And also there is a table in same page to display submitted records. Table contains four columns. Those are Id , Name , Delete and Edit.  I want to load test edit function. I have CSV file its have 100 records with employee id and name. I use 100 threads in same sampler. So i want to know how i can change the script for edit each and every inserted record in each sampler sequentially in table.

Comment: because table row count change with inserted records.  i want to click on edit in correct row for particular request.